# Cisco Router - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, router

I have never used a Cisco product and have hand my but handed to me trying to use set it up.
We have a second hand Cisco router 1900 series(1941). I have connected the router via the light blue and yellow cable. I can not connect to the router via command prompt. It gives me a bad command error, when trying to set up via fast step set up, I get IP overlap error.

ipconfig details is:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::85f2:12cb:11a4:7986%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.7
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Tunnel adapter isatap.{B5E91286-8FD5-4896-85CD-B492F4E7D9F7}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:8f0:28fb:d6c7:f6e7
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8f0:28fb:d6c7:f6e7%15
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

But it i put for my ip 192.168.1.7 and 192.168.1.1 for the router, i get the overlapping error,

Please please if any one can help me please

Comment: did it get reset to factory when you took ownership?

Comment: Hi Frank Thommas, No i can seem to get access to it to reset it i did try via command prompt command Router>enable and Router but it gave me the invalid command error, so i was unable to reset it my self, thank you very much for your willingness to help me

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but it sounds like you're trying to access the router console using the DOS command prompt in windows, which is not supported.  You'll need a program such as [Hyperterminal](http://www.hilgraeve.com/hyperterminal/) or [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to make the serial connection to the router.  Once you've gotten one running, ensure you're initiating a "Serial" connection (both applications have other types of connections they can be used for, which won't be helpful for this particular case).

Settings for making the serial connection should be as follows:

```
Speed (baud): 9600
Data Bits: 8
Stop Bits: 1
Parity: None
Flow Control: None
```

As for which serial device to use, if it's a built-in serial port you're using, it will almost always be "COM1".  If you're using a USB-to-Serial adapter (fairly common these days), then you'll want to go into the Windows Device Manager (in Win7, right click "Computer", click "Manage", and select "Device Manager") and click on "Ports (COM & LPT)".  Your connection should be listed in the form " (COM<#>)".  The COM# is the serial port to select in either Hyperterminal or Putty (obviously replacing "#" with the number listed in Device Manager).

For Cisco's own documentation on doing this in Hyperterminal, click [here](http://www-tss.cisco.com/eservice/compass/common/tasks/task_console_port_connect.htm).

Other software that can be used for this purpose on windows includes TeraTerm (free as in beer) and SecureCRT(non-free, but there is a free trial period).